# Case accept being empty or specific characters

Tags: bash, shell-script

Doing some media processing here:

```
case "$3" in
all)
  :
  ;;
[a-z][a-z][a-z])
  if [ "$2" == "subtitles" ]; then switches="$switches -s $3"
  if [ "$2" == "audio" ]; then switches="$switches -a $3"
  ;;
*)
  printf 'Invalid language code for language (should be 3-letter ISO-639 or "all"): %s\n' "$2"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

This is to make sure that `$3` is either `all` or 3 letters between a-z. My issue is that `*` makes my command fail if `$3` is empty. If I remove it I can continue but then I cannot make sure that `$3` is either `all` or 3 letters between a-z.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `$3` is empty?

Comment: @Kusalananda  do nothing. Just not fail. I want to fail only if `$3` is not empty, not `all`, and not `3 letters between a-z`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pattern

```
all|""
```

to match either `all` or an empty string.

```
case "$3" in
    all|"") ;;
    [a-z][a-z][a-z])
        other-code ;;
    *)
        catch-all-code
esac
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work...I was trying `""|*` but that does not work.

Comment: @Freedo `""|*` would match "an empty string, or anything".